# Are there any design pattern to data binding in event driven architecture?

Tags: design, architecture, event-programming, websockets

I develop a browser based game with node.js in back and HTML5 canvas in front-end.
It use WebSockets for communication.

My plan is to generate business events in client side, e.g.: "finishJob".
Client will store all relevant information up to date.

- client doesn't have to call server every time it need some data e.g: players money
- to achieve this, client will subscribe to players channel
- every online player has its own channel, like a chat room
- every time something happen with a player, its channel fire an event with players new data

In MVC pattern in here the model is Player, the View is the HTML5 Canvas, but i need 2 type of controllers:

1. controller to handle business events
2. controller to handle channels and subscribers

My questions: Is this a viable option?
If yes, are there any design pattern similar for this, or any article about this kind of architecture? Are there any naming conventions ("controllers", "handlers", "channels"...)?

Comment: It would be worth reading up on [FireBase](https://www.firebase.com/) to see how they handle this

Comment: Thank you! I see FireBase is very similar. And through FireBase i found WAMP: http://wamp.ws/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Yes

#### ...see the link below for this pattern...

If you're writing an application which uses *Peers* -- or any complex app which requires robust *Object-Networks* I would use an Event-Driven Architecture.

#### Using a Mediator or EventHub (Event-Aggrigator)

The simplest approach would be to implement the *Mediator Pattern* designed by [Addy Osmoni](http://addyosmani.com/largescalejavascript/).

This allows you to write something like:

```
// core.js
mediator.subscribe('newMemberAdded', function newMemberAddedHandler(id){
    this.membersModule.add(id);
});
```

...

```
// membersUI.js
$('#addMember').click(function(){
    ...
    mediator.publish('newMemberAdded', 998);
    ...
});
```

With this, the only *Coupling* your modules require is a reference to `mediator` in order to communicate with other modules.

Using a Mediator is very powerful and will make your modules more *Liftable* (loose coupling), however, there are some conventions **you should consider** while developing an EDA:

- Modules only publish *interests* -- **not Query+Command events**

  - e.g: eventHub.fire('buttonClicked') **NOT** eventHub.fire('get:membersList', function(){ ... })
- Query+Command Channels *Are reserved for Core/Facade interaction* (see Osmoni's post)
- Work-around those *Noun-Verb-Adjective* channel-names:

  - e.g: `'log'`, `'start'`, `'change'`, `'notice'` all can be seen as a command or something that happend. You can add the *ing* conjugate to obviate this (`'starting'`)
- Listen Before You Speak! -- Otherwise you may miss events
- *Visit the link above for more*

Additionally, you can bind your Mediator to a *WebWorker* or *SharedWorker* to share state between browser tabs (etc) and bind your worker to an *EventHub* on your server for an even cleaner coupling.

I know this post is somewhat ad hoc, but I hope its enough to get you started!

Comment: You bet, blaskov! Glad to help out here. I'm also developing a Mediation framework (emcdjs) which uses promises, along with *abstractChannels* [e.g: `error://{module}/:message`] -- using MVC-style channel routing & event streaming -- which I'm pioneering as I work out the kinks. If this interests you, I could push it to GitHub (currently private on BitBucket) if you want to also pilot it. Anyway, thanks for the kuddos!